# sys.exc_info not tracing complete stack trace on capture and raise?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I want to catch and re-raise the exception, which i have been able to do. But the issue is that the trace shown after re-raising is not as detailed as the one thrown without capturing.

Another curious thing is `sys.exc_info()[2]` which i am using for traceback just shows the outer level trace and doesn't dig inside the library. Whereas when i use `traceback.format_exc()` it just shows the trace inside the library. I want both of the traces, which is actually thrown if i do not capture and re-raise.

This is what i am doing:

```
def raise_location_suggest_error(function):
    def wrap_exceptions(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            # print traceback.format_exc()
            raise (LocationSuggestError(str(e)), None, sys.exc_info()[2])
    return wrap_exceptions

@raise_location_suggest_error
def error_throwing_method():
    # some error thrown
```

The stack trace from above is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/foo/web/base_cmd.py", line 453, in run
    return self.execute()
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/cmds/_request_mapper.py", line 400, in execute
    return action(**match)
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/cmds/location_suggest.py", line 28, in json_suggestions
    return LocationSuggest(self).json_suggestions()
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/foo/web/cmd_helpers/location_suggest.py", line 45, in json_suggestions
    _, suggestions = self.get_suggestions()
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/foo/web/cmd_helpers/location_suggest.py", line 81, in get_suggestions
    .suggest(prefix, country, state, city, recent_locations, exps)
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/virtualenv_run/lib/python2.6/site-packages/foo_clientlib/decorators/clog_call.py", line 108, in wrapper
    result = method(given_self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/foo/component/search/location_suggest.py", line 113, in suggest
    None, sys.exc_info()[2])
```

Uncommenting `print traceback.format_exc()` gives:

```
File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/foo/component/search/location_suggest.py", line 105, in suggest
    AsynchronousHttpClient(headers=self._headers))
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/virtualenv_run/lib/python2.6/site-packages/swaggerpy/client.py", line 110, in get_client
    return factory(*args, **kwargs).swagger_client
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/virtualenv_run/lib/python2.6/site-packages/swaggerpy/client.py", line 71, in __call__
    **kwargs)
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/virtualenv_run/lib/python2.6/site-packages/swaggerpy/client.py", line 79, in build_cached_client
    return CachedClient(SwaggerClient(*args, **kwargs), timeout)
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/virtualenv_run/lib/python2.6/site-packages/swaggerpy/client.py", line 287, in __init__
    self._api_docs = loader.load_resource_listing(url_or_resource)
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/virtualenv_run/lib/python2.6/site-packages/swaggerpy/swagger_model.py", line 160, in load_resource_listing
    resource_listing = json_load_url(self.http_client, resources_url)
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/virtualenv_run/lib/python2.6/site-packages/swaggerpy/swagger_model.py", line 122, in json_load_url
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/nail/home/prateek/pg/foo-main/virtualenv_run/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 725, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
```

And on removing the decorator `@raise_location_suggest_error` basically gives the concatenation of first and second traceback, which is what i want. What can i do to re-raise and get *full* stack trace? I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

It was a dumb mistake from my end. `sys.exc_info` trace was not even read by `raise` as the third argument. `raise a, b, c` is different from `raise(a, b, c)`. If one needs to break up into two lines, use `\` instead of applying parenthesis. Changing to `raise a, b, c` solved my isssue.